# Is there an equivalent function to the b'' byte literal?

Tags: python, encoding, byte

I am working with a text file containing lines of data that include both ASCII and escaped byte data and I am trying to find a function in Python to encode the lines of text into bytes data for sending to another PC over UDP.

The string I am trying to encode is captured OSC data and looks similar to this line:

```
#bundle\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x008/tracking/trackers/head/position\x00\x00\x00\x00,fff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xbd\xb8\x93\xbd\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x004/tracking/trackers/6/position\x00\x00\x00,fff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xbe\xdb\xe9\x9e\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x004/tracking/trackers/6/rotation\x00\x00\x00,fff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x00\x00\x00\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x004/tracking/trackers/1/position\x00\x00\x00,fff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xbfAO\x80\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x004/tracking/trackers/1/rotation\x00\x00\x00,fff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x00\x00\x00\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x004/tracking/trackers/4/position\x00\x00\x00,fff\x00\x00\x00\x00<]\x01P\xbfF[\x9d>\xa2\xaa\xf2\x00\x00\x004/tracking/trackers/4/rotation\x00\x00\x00,fff\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc2\xad\xe3\x91A\xbc\xd2\xec@\xff)\xcb\x00\x00\x004/tracking/trackers/5/position\x00\x00\x00,fff\x00\x00\x00\x00>:=\xcd\xbf\x90vV\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x004/tracking/trackers/5/rotation\x00\x00\x00,fff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x00\x00\x00\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x004/tracking/trackers/2/position\x00\x00\x00,fff\x00\x00\x00\x00<]\x01L\xbf\xa2\x93Y>\xa2\xaa\xf2\x00\x00\x004/tracking/trackers/2/rotation\x00\x00\x00,fff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00A\xf9Op\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x004/tracking/trackers/3/position\x00\x00\x00,fff\x00\x00\x00\x00>\xb28^\xbf\x92\xc6L>\xea\x81o\x00\x00\x004/tracking/trackers/3/rotation\x00\x00\x00,fff\x00\x00\x00\x00BJ\xd5.B\xfd\xb4(C#\xcf`'
```

But when I attempt to encode the string to bytes Python is including new double backslashes in the bytes object:

```
b1 = b'tracking/trackers/head/position\x00\x00\x00\x00'
b2 = r"tracking/trackers/head/position\x00\x00\x00\x00".encode()

print(b1)
print(b2)

b'tracking/trackers/head/position\x00\x00\x00\x00'
b'tracking/trackers/head/position\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00' #added double backslashes
```

How do I parse or encode a string to produce the equivalent as a byte literal in Python 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the correct *bytes* for it to be able to encode back correctly.

See the below example:

```py
b1 = b'tracking/trackers/head/position\x00\x00\x00\x00'
print(b1)
print(b1.decode())
print(b1.decode().encode())
```

```
b'tracking/trackers/head/position\x00\x00\x00\x00'
tracking/trackers/head/position
b'tracking/trackers/head/position\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

For an explanation as to why this works, I would recommend reading this answer: [What exactly do "u" and "r" string prefixes do, and what are raw string literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-prefixes-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals)

Notably:

> A "raw string literal" is a slightly different syntax for a string literal, in which a backslash, , is taken as meaning "just a backslash" (except when it comes right before a quote that would otherwise terminate the literal) -- no "escape sequences" to represent newlines, tabs, backspaces, form-feeds, and so on. In normal string literals, each backslash must be doubled up to avoid being taken as the start of an escape sequence.

Where you're using the `r'stringhere'` thats messing with the backslashes.

Update 1:
As for alternatives to using `b''` as mentioned in title there is the `bytes.decode` function I used in the example, the docs for that are [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode)
Another alternative is the `bytes` function, docs for that are [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytes)
And an example that below:

```py
b1 = b'tracking/trackers/head/position\x00\x00\x00\x00'
print(b1)
print(bytes(b1.decode(), 'utf-8'))
print(b1.decode().encode())
```

```
b'tracking/trackers/head/position\x00\x00\x00\x00'
b'tracking/trackers/head/position\x00\x00\x00\x00'
b'tracking/trackers/head/position\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

And I assumed you had the bytes to begin with, otherwise just a normal string would also behave in the manor you require too.

```py
b1 = 'tracking/trackers/head/position\x00\x00\x00\x00'
print(b1)
print(b1.encode())
```

```
tracking/trackers/head/position
b'tracking/trackers/head/position\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Update 2:

Okay so if you're file wasnt written correctly and the escaped characters are literally just individual characters (not encoded/decoded) and you want to parse them as if they were, you can use the 'unicode-escape' encoding to decode the double escaped codes `\\x00` you get when reading.
Note the encoding to `latin1` to maintain the bytes before decoding to whichever encoding it was originally.

```py
f = open("output.txt", "rb")
b2 = f.read().decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin1').splitlines()[0] #.decode('utf-8', errors='ignore')
f.close()
```

```
b"#bundle\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x008/tracking/trackers/head/position\x00\x00\x00\x00,fff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xbd\xb8\x93\xbd\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x004/tracking/trackers/6/position\x00\x00\x00,fff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xbe\xdb\xe9\x9e\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x004/tracking/trackers/6/rotation\x00\x00\x00,fff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x00\x00\x00\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x004/tracking/trackers/1/position\x00\x00\x00,fff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xbfAO\x80\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x004/tracking/trackers/1/rotation\x00\x00\x00,fff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x00\x00\x00\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x004/tracking/trackers/4/position\x00\x00\x00,fff\x00\x00\x00\x00<]\x01P\xbfF[\x9d>\xa2\xaa\xf2\x00\x00\x004/tracking/trackers/4/rotation\x00\x00\x00,fff\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc2\xad\xe3\x91A\xbc\xd2\xec@\xff)\xcb\x00\x00\x004/tracking/trackers/5/position\x00\x00\x00,fff\x00\x00\x00\x00>:=\xcd\xbf\x90vV\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x004/tracking/trackers/5/rotation\x00\x00\x00,fff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x00\x00\x00\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x004/tracking/trackers/2/position\x00\x00\x00,fff\x00\x00\x00\x00<]\x01L\xbf\xa2\x93Y>\xa2\xaa\xf2\x00\x00\x004/tracking/trackers/2/rotation\x00\x00\x00,fff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00A\xf9Op\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x004/tracking/trackers/3/position\x00\x00\x00,fff\x00\x00\x00\x00>\xb28^\xbf\x92\xc6L>\xea\x81o\x00\x00\x004/tracking/trackers/3/rotation\x00\x00\x00,fff\x00\x00\x00\x00BJ\xd5.B\xfd\xb4(C#\xcf`'"
```

Comment: This only works for string literals, but how would I implement this using a string from a file?

Comment: @Logic1 when you read from the file you need to specify to read bytes eg: 
```python
file = open("file.whatever", "rb")
literal = file.read() #or alternative reading methods.
```

And from there its the exact same as having a bytes of `b'tracking/trackers/head/position\x00\x00\x00\x00'` and the code in answer should behave the exact same.

And from that you can then `wb` into a file with bytes and no need to encode to string.

Comment: When I add "rb" it still adds double backslashes to every line of data when printed.

Comment: Here is the full txt file: https://www.mediafire.com/file_premium/6p0egcuzy1lzp94/output.txt

Comment: When testing this does indeed work as per answer code:

https://codeshare.io/vAwolk  

b'tracking/trackers/head/position\x00\x00\x00\x00'  
b'tracking/trackers/head/position\x00\x00\x00\x00'

Comment: But I don't have the ability to write a new file. I only have the original file as it is.

Comment: @Logic1 I see, so the file when written wasn't written as bytes and they aren't escaped utf-8 values but just characters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256859/discussion-between-jaxkdev-and-logic1).

Comment: That is correct, the file doesn't include the bytes but instead includes the escaped bytes. I am trying to find a way to encode each line so the result is the equivalent to the byte literals for the same string.

Comment: `b2 = f.read().decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin1').decode('ENCODINGHERE')` Replacing `encodinghere` with the encoding you expect should work

Comment: The solution was `line.decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin1')` this is very helpful !! Thank you !!